# Symfony2 removing from collection does not persist OneToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have 2 doctrine elements lets say parent and child with a one to many relationship. The child is the owning side, and stores the id of the parent in the database.

When I remove a child from the parent by removing it from the collection on the parent, and I persist it, the child nor its relationship is removed.

Is this normal behaviour and do I have to say `$parent->removeChild($child)` for each child I want to remove? Or do I have something wrong in annotation, in which case I will post my code.

EDIT: can someone explain why this doest work on one to many but does work on many to many ?

Comment: Please don't include "Thanks in advance." in your question. It is useless noise.

Comment: noted, will keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion:

```
$parent->removeChild($child);
```

is the way to go.

Comment: Can you explain why a many to many persists out of the box, and a one to many doesn't ?